# Crashes on Simulator but not on devices: -[NSTaggedPointerString stringValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, error-handling, ios-simulator, nsnumber

I implemented some public function which can make me program more concisely. But I have a problem on my simulator but it's good on devices.
I am 100% sure the uid I stored in UserDefaults is a NSNumber. But why it's only crashes on simulators?

Code:

```
+(NSString *) keyForUserProfileName{
    NSNumber *uid = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"uid"];
    NSLog(@"my uid is %@", uid);
    NSString *key = [@"UserProfileNameFor" stringByAppendingString: [uid stringValue]];
    NSLog(@"my key is %@", key);

     return key;
}
```

Error:

```
my uid is 11803624
-[NSTaggedPointerString stringValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa0079ea9d7eca1c8
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSTaggedPointerString stringValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa0079ea9d7eca1c8'
```

uid assign code:

```
NSNumber *uid = [loginResult objectForKey:@"uid"];
[prefs setObject:uid forKey:@"uid"];
```

**EDIT**-----------------------------------------------------------------------

After I inserted these two lines after `NSNumber *uid...`line, the program goes through both simulators and devices. But I have totally no idea why it was wrong.

```
int uidint = [uid intValue];
NSString *uidString = [@(uidint) stringValue];
```

Comment: you are trying to convert string to string value, direcltly use ***NSString *uid***

Comment: Change your uid assign code into `    NSNumber *uid = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:[[loginResult objectForKey:@"uid"] integerValue]];
`

Comment: @Subramanian You are right man!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your uid assign code into

```
NSNumber *uid = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:[[loginResult objectForKey:@"uid"] integerValue]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `uid's` type should be consistent with the type when you put it into `NSUserDefaults`. When you write OC, XCode do not know whether the `uid's` type is `NSNumber` or not until runtime.
So change the type like this `NSString *uid = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"uid"];` (if you put a `NSString uid` into `NSUserDefaults`) and have a try.

---------------------------------update------------------------------

A tricky method is that after you get `uid` from `NSUserDefaults`, you can check the type of `uid` and then change the type then according to your need.

Comment: Thank you for reply. Please take a look of my new edit.

Comment: @KevinScience Whether `loginResult` is a `NSDictionary` and what is value's type when you put it into this `loginResult` ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your `UserDefaults` contains `NSNumber object` as value of `uid` and it is not string or integer or etc. I mean you should set your number like,

```
 NSNumber *number = yournumber here ;

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:number forKey:@"uid"];
```

If you are setting string object then you not need to convert it in string again!

Comment: Thank you for reply. Please take a look of my new edit.

Comment: are you sure that your `[loginResult objectForKey:@"uid"];`  returning `NSNumber` object and not other ?

Comment: once try to replace `NSNumber *uid = [loginResult objectForKey:@"uid"];` with  `NSNumber *uid = (NSNumber*)[loginResult objectForKey:@"uid"];`

Answer (score 0):

I think your are not set the value of `uid`, once you set then you can retrieve, check out below code for your reference.

```
+(NSString *) keyForUserProfileName{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:10] forKey:@"uid"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

    NSNumber *uid = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"uid"];
    NSString *key = [@"UserProfileNameFor : " stringByAppendingString: [uid stringValue]];
    return key;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. Please take a look of my new edit.

Comment: Do one thing, create one other project and add this code in that and try, it's work in other project or not, If not then I will guide what is the exact problem you facing.